# MVC find out if current web request is for an controller/action or a static resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed an MVC web application, and for every request that comes in I need to change the culture. I have the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Called from every HTTP request
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Sender object</param>
/// <param name="e">Event args</param>
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SetCulture();
}
```

Now the setting of the culture works perfectly, however it runs through this piece of code for EVERY request, including calls for javascript files, css files, images, fonts etc. I only want this method running for actions.

**Is there anyway at this stage of a request (i.e. Application_BeginRequest) to figure out if it is a controller/action request or a static resource request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive all your controllers from a BaseController (which itself derives from Controller) and put your code in the OnActionExecuting function in your base controller.

```
public BaseController : Controller
{
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
                SetCulture();
        }
}
```

Comment: What happens if a view calls many partial page renders? Will this then be called many times? I need to keep the number of calls to a minimum due to its expense

Comment: Yes it will be called every time but there is a property called IsChildAction which is true for partials rendered from views. So you should only call SetCulture if IsChildAction is false.  See this post from haacked http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: ps: Calling RenderAction() will invoke the controller pipeline. Partials won't so don't worry if you just have views in partials